# Multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ado.net

I've read through at least a dozen other questions just like this one, but I am having trouble grasping some of this stuff.

I'm used to developing ASP.NET MVC3 with repositories and code-first entities linking to the entity framework.

I've recently switched to database-first ADO.NET with services development.
I find this to be very clean since I can access stuff through my foreign keys.

Anyway, my old save methods seem to be broken since I constantly get this error

> An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of
>   IEntityChangeTracker

So here's a look at my save action and my service:

Action:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddReview(Review review, int id)
        {
            User loggedInUser = userService.GetUserByusername(User.Identity.Name);
            review.WriterId = loggedInUser.UserId;
            review.ProductId = id;

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                reviewService.Save(review);
                Product product = productService.GetProduct(id);

                if(product.Quantity>=1)
                    product.Quantity--;
                product.TimesBought++;

                productService.UpdateRating(product, reviewService);

                loggedInUser.GoldCoins -= product.Price;
                Session["goldCoins"] = loggedInUser.GoldCoins;
                userService.Save(loggedInUser);
                productService.Save(product);

            }
            else
            {
                return View(review);
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Answers", new { reviewId = review.ReviewId });
```

Service:

```
public class ReviewService : Service<Review, CapstoneEntities>
    {

        ...

        public void Save(Review review)
        {


        using (var db = new CapstoneEntities())
        {
            if (review.ReviewId == 0)
            {
                db.Reviews.Add(review);
                db.Entry(review).State = EntityState.Added;
            }
            else
            {
                db.Entry(review).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

My suspicion is with this line of code: using `(var db = new CapstoneEntities())` but I'm not sure how else to do this. Again, this worked perfectly with my old way of doing things but now I get errors on just about ever CRUD operation.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is being caused by having an entity belong to multiple DataContexts. Whatever code that is calling that action should use the same DataContext to create the entity as the one used to persist it to the datastore.

In most instances you should only keep one instance of the DataContext. You can use a DI framework like Castle to define/store a dependency (in this case the DataContext) as Transient or PerWebRequest and inject it into the service and controller, so you'll always have a reference to the same instance of the DataContext.

Comment: The action is being called by form, which has far as I know has no knowledge of a DataContext.

Comment: Is `Review` an entity, model or both? If it is a model, are you using a DataContext to retrieve it?

Comment: Well entities are like models, aren't they? But they were auto-generated by ADO.NET into a Models.tt file.

Comment: Using an entity as an MVC model is tricky sometimes, especially when tracking the entity through the MVC pipeline - I'd recommend either abstracting the model and entity from one another (AutoMapper is handy when doing this) or using DI to use a PerWebRequest dependency on the DataContext - not sure how/if the later works with T4 templates.

Answer (score 2):

I am new to MVC & Entity frame work. I got same problem after fighting a lot
This solution worked for me. Hope it can be useful for you guys.

```
var mediaItem = db.MediaItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == mediaItemViewModel.Id);
    mediaItem.Name = mediaItemViewModel.Name;
    mediaItem.Description = mediaItemViewModel.Description;
    mediaItem.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
    mediaItem.FileName = mediaItem.FileName;
    mediaItem.Size = KBToMBConversion(mediaItemViewModel.Size);
    mediaItem.Type = mediaItem.Type;

//db.Entry(mediaItem).State = EntityState.Modified;// coment This line
db.SaveChanges();
```

Cause you are reading the the whole object from db and holding it in the current context and when you try to modify the entity state its tells you already one entity attached to the current context. just call save changes it will save it.